# Tag head after closing tab body

Tags: html

Hi everyone
 is it possible, in HTML, to insert the `<head>` after the closing tag `</body>`? Or do I have to code before the `<head>` and after the `<body>`?

I was reading at w3schools.com about css, and it sais: 
 "Note: If the link to the external style sheet is placed after the internal style sheet in HTML , the external style sheet will override the internal style sheet!"

the question is how can I put and external style sheet after an internal style sheet if the external style sheet is declared in the head which is always before the body?

Comment: but why are you trying to do that?

Comment: If you explain why you want to do that, we can suggest a better, appropriate solution.

Comment: No you cannot do like that,`head` should be closed before you open `body` tag.May i know what you want to code as you mentioned in the question?

Comment: @antox Well, dont use internal style sheets, except when you have to override something unique. And even then you could do it inside .css external file.

Comment: I know I know, but I would like to know how it is possible

Comment: First, don't use w3schools. Second, that is about two **`<style>`** tags inside **one** `<head>` tag, not two `<head>` tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

An HTML element must consist of exactly one HTML element with its children being one HEAD element and one BODY element, in that order.

The start and end tags for all three of those elements are optional, but you can't explicitly place them in any other order.

Browsers will attempt error recovery if you place the HEAD after the BODY, but you shouldn't depend on this.

> external style sheet after an internal style sheet if the external style sheet is declared in the head which is always before the body?

You are confusing internal stylesheets (defined with the `<script>` element, which (like `<link>` which is used for external stylesheets) must appear in the `<head>`) with inline styles (defined by the `style=` attribute, which can appear on almost any element, including most that appear in the `<body>`.

Nothing about the order that stylesheets appear in can alter the influence of inline style, since they will always have [a higher specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: @antox as you accepted this answer already I would recommend you to use the W3C validator as guide: https://validator.w3.org/ it will tell you where you have things wrong bout your syntax.

Comment: I noticed you rejected the edit I made to this answer. Could you clarify your suggestion that "internal stylesheets [are] defined with the <script> element"?  

I must admit, I don't quite see why making the tag references more consistent and adding a reference to the W3C spec is so objectionable.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't i think this may help you..

[image]

For more read this http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/html-document-structure.htm