# Why would HEAD tag come after BODY tag?

Tags: html, wordpress, debugging

This is a Wordpress site, and I think that everything is in the proper order, and called at the proper time.  However, in the browser, the `HEAD` tag (containing the correct info) is being outputted after the `BODY` tag.

My suspicion is that there is an unclosed tag somewhere, and Chrome is autofixing it.  Firefox and Internet Explorer won't render the site at all, but don't put the `HEAD` last, and don't offer any helpful errors in the error console.

The server side debug.log and error.log report nothing, but there is definitely something off.

First.  Is my premise that there is likely an unclosed tag somewhere likely correct?  Or is it more likely that there is some other reason?  And if so, or if not, any tips on debugging this particular nest of rats?

:: **Necessary Code** ::

---

`header.php`

```
<?php
    /**
    * header.php
    *
    * Header for wordpress default template
    */
    ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
      <!--
           broke up viewport meta tag
           for formatting 
           in real file, all on single line
      -->
     <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width,
       initial-scale=1,
       user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1" />
        <!-- TODO:  Set Meta Values In Header -->
        <title><?php the_title(); ?></title>
            <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <?
        // defined at template_redirect
        global $body_class;
    ?>
    <body class="<?php echo $body_class; ?>">
    <?php
        // defined at template_redirect with hook
        global $header_type;
        // main navbar 
        get_template_part('inc/header/nav','primary');
        echo build_header( $header_type );
```

---

`main template body`
`// main.php`

```
<?php

    /**
     * Template Name: Main
     *
     * Main Template page for pht-theme
     *
     * @package pht-theme
     */

        get_header();
        $page=my_page_id();
?>
    <div class="main-content container <?php echo $page; ?>">
<?php
    _build_page( $page );
?>
    </div>
<?php
  get_footer();
?>
```

---

Be happy to include more if it will help.

Thanks

::**Update**::

---

I have discovered that if I don't bother to put my scripts in the footer when using `wp_register_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_scripts`, this stops happening.   Strange.

Comment: show your header.php please.

Answer (score 2):

> Is my premise that there is likely an unclosed tag somewhere likely correct?

No.  Check it in Firefox.  You'll see that a missing closing tag has a different effect.  The rest of the HTML is appended to it.  The order of `<head>` and `<body>` are not reversed.

For example, you can simulate that effect by doing this crazy test:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', function(){
    ?>
    <script>console.log('does it auto close the missing tag?');
    <?php
}, 9999);
```

Running this code will demonstrate that the rendered HTML markup in the browser displays as:

```
<script>console.log('does it auto close the missing tag?');</head><body>
```

> Or is it more likely that there is some other reason?

Yes.

> And if so, or if not, any tips on debugging this particular nest of rats?

I'd start by opening the theme's `header.php` file. This file is responsible for loading the site's header, i.e. `<head>`.  Typically, the starting `<body>` structure is also found in this file.  For example, you can see it the HTML markup structure in the popular [_s theme](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/header.php#L22).

Open the file and make sure the `<head>` markup is first in the file.  Then investigate where the `<body>` markup is defined.  Make sure it is loaded after the head.

In some themes, I've seen the head and body broken out into partial templates.  If this is the case for your theme, check the order of how they are loaded.

You can amend your question and supply the `header.php` file for us to take a closer look.

#### Similar Question

This question is related and somewhat similar to give you some reference:

[Tag head after closing tab body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515846/tag-head-after-closing-tab-body)

Comment: I'll get back to this and update.   For now - thanks for providing some sanity for my evening

Comment: please review updated code in question.  Your notes have been helpful, but I have yet to push through.  Thanks